# How can I read user input in Rust?

Tags: input, io, rust

I intend to make a tokenizer. I need to read every line the user types and stop reading once the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

I searched around and only found [one example](http://rusttutorial.blogspot.ca/2012/09/command-line-user-input-stdin.html) on Rust IO which does not even compile. I looked at the `io` module's documentation and found that the `read_line()` function is part of the `ReaderUtil` interface, but `stdin()` returns a `Reader` instead.

The code that I would like would essentially look like the following in C++:

```cpp
vector<string> readLines () {
    vector<string> allLines;
    string line;

    while (cin >> line) {
        allLines.push_back(line);
    }

    return allLines;
}
```

> <sub>This question refers to parts of Rust that predate Rust 1.0, but the general concept is still valid in Rust 1.0.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust 0.4, use the `ReaderUtil` trait to access the `read_line` function. Note that you need to explicitly cast the value to a trait type, for example, `reader as io::ReaderUtil`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut allLines = ~[];
    let reader = io::stdin();

    while !reader.eof() {
            allLines.push((reader as io::ReaderUtil).read_line());
    }

    for allLines.each |line| {
            io::println(fmt!("%s", *line));
    }
}
```

> <sub>This answer predates Rust 1.0. Please see the other answers for modern solutions.</sub>

Comment: I don't think I quite understand how cast works in Rust. :-( It doesn't seem all that similar to casts I'm used to in C/C++. What does it mean when you cast something to a trait type? Does it simply instruct the compilers to let you bind those methods from the trait type onto the thing you're casting from? (in this case, it's whatever returns from `stdin()`...)

Comment: I am not well familiar with Rust internals, but I guess the cast is for the type checker because the actual method to call is decided at runtime.

Comment: hmm okay. This is the kind of solution that I wanted. So your answer is accepted :-) Thanks!

Comment: @BeyondSora, it would be nice if you could accept the more upvoted answer below so it appears at the top.

Answer (score 170):

In Rust 1.x and later (see [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/index.html#iterator-types)):

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: This can actually be `for io::stdin().each_line |line| { .. }`, or using [`extra::fileinput`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/extra/fileinput.html): `for fileinput::input |line| { .. }`

Comment: The rust 1.0.0 version (top) no longer compiles (even when std::io is changed to std::old_io). :/

Comment: @weberc2 Yes, see [this rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21070) and [RFC PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/899).

Answer (score 15):

As of 17 April 2015, from `mdcox` on the Firefox Rust [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) channel.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let input = &mut String::new();

    loop {
        input.clear();
        stdin.read_line(input);
        println!("{}", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do `stdin.read_line(input);`, the compiler warns me about this line being not used.

Comment: @yagooar, it should warn about the *result* not being used, not the line. That means reading from stdin might have resulted in an error but you're not checking for it.

Answer (score 4):

In Rust 1.0 and later, you can use the [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) method on anything that implements the [`std::io::BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait to obtain an iterator over lines in the input. You could also use [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) , but using the iterator is more likely what you'd want. Here is a version of the function in the question using iterators; see below for a more detailed explanation. ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=84712f10131b11a07030a4f4585cccc4&version=stable))

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

pub fn read_lines() -> Vec<String> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let stdin_lock = stdin.lock();
    let vec = stdin_lock.lines().filter_map(|l| l.ok()).collect();

    vec
}
```

And here's a version that is more like the C++ version in the question, but is not really the idiomatic way to do this in Rust ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d1fd3aa77f8a1475e4b4a3b1487e6645&version=stable)):

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

pub fn read_lines() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let mut string = String::new();

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut stdin_lock = stdin.lock();

    while let Ok(len) = stdin_lock.read_line(&mut string) {
        if len > 0 {
           vec.push(string);
           string = String::new();
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    vec
}
```

To obtain something that implements `BufRead`, which is needed to call `lines()` or `read_line()`, you call [`std::io::stdin()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdin.html) to obtain a handle to standard input, and then call [`lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) on the result of that to obtain exclusive control of the standard input stream (you must have exclusive control to obtain a `BufRead`, because otherwise the buffering could produce arbitrary results if two threads were reading from stdin at once).

To collect the result into a `Vec<String>`, you can use the [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) method on an iterator. `lines()` returns an iterator over `Result<String>`, so we need to handle error cases in which a line could not be read; for this example, we just ignore errors with a `filter_map` that just skips any errors.

The C++ like version uses `read_line`, which appends the read line to a given string, and we then push the string into our `Vec`. Because we transfer ownership of the string to the `Vec` when we do that, and because `read_line` would otherwise keep appending to the `string`, we need to allocate a new string for each loop (this appears to be a bug in the original C++ version in the question, in which the same string is shared and so will keep accumulating every line). We use [`while let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/if-let.html#while-let) to continue to read until we hit an error, and we break if we ever read zero bytes which indicates the end of the input.

Answer (score 3):

The question is to read lines from standard input and return a vector. In Rust 1.7:

```
fn readlines() -> Vec<String> {
    use std::io::prelude::*;
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let v = stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
    v
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways I can think of.

Read all the input into single `String`

```
let mut input = String::new();
io::stdin().read_to_end(&mut input);
```

Read lines into `Vector`. This one doesn't `panic` when reading a line fails. Instead it skips that failed line.

```
let stdin = io::stdin();
let locked = stdin.lock();
let v: Vec<String> = locked.lines().filter_map(|line| line.ok()).collect();
```

Furthermore if you want to parse it:

After reading it into string do this. You can parse it to other collections that implements `FromIterator`. Contained elements in the collection also must implement `FromStr`. As long as the trait constraint satisfies, you can change Vec to any `Collection:FromIterator`, `Collection<T: FromStr>`:

```
let v: Vec<i32> = "4 -42 232".split_whitespace().filter_map(|w| w.parse().ok()).collect();
```

Also, you can use it on the `StdinLock`:

```
let vv: Vec<Vec<i32>> = locked
    .lines()
    .filter_map(|l|
        l.ok().map(|s|
            s.split_whitespace().filter_map(|word| word.parse().ok()).collect()
        )
    )
    .collect();
```

Answer (score 2):

Uh... After many trials and errors, I've found a solution.

I'd still like to see a better solution so I'm not going to accept my own solution.

The code below prints exactly what the user inputs.

```
mod tokenizer {

    pub fn read () -> ~[int] {
        let reader = io::stdin();
        let mut bytes: ~[int] = ~[];

        loop {
            let byte: int = reader.read_byte();
            if byte < 0 {
                return bytes;
            }
            bytes += [byte];
        }
    }
}

fn main () {
    let bytes: ~[int] = tokenizer::read();
    for bytes.each |byte| {
        io::print(#fmt("%c", *byte as char));
    }
}
```

> <sub>This answer predates Rust 1.0. Please see the other answers for modern solutions.</sub>

Comment: [Rustfmt](https://play.rust-lang.org/) doesn't like it: *"error: expected type, found `~` ... `pub fn read () -> ~[int] {`"*

Answer (score 1):

From *[Processing a Guess](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#processing-a-guess)*

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

While there are many different ways of doing this in Rust, I think this is the simplest to implement.

```rust
use std::io;
// ...
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("Your input was `{}`", input);
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Rust 1.62, reading lines of user input is a bit simpler than it was before.  Now that [`Stdin::lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lines) is stable, it is no longer necessary to worry about locking, since `lines()` takes care of that for you:

```rust
fn main() {
    for line in std::io::stdin().lines() {
        println!("line entered: {}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

If you'd like to build a `Vec` of `String`s, the new method lets you do that in one line:

```rust
let inputs: Vec<_> = std::io::stdin().lines().map(|line| line.unwrap()).collect();
```