# How can I read a single line from stdin in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm asking for the equivalent of `fgets()` in C.

```
let line = ...;
println!("You entered: {}", line);
```

I've read [How to read user input in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579266/how-to-read-user-input-in-rust), but it asks how to read multiple lines; I want only one line.

I also read [How do I read a single String from standard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528998/how-do-i-read-a-single-string-from-standard-input), but I'm not sure if it behaves like `fgets()` or `sscanf("%s",...)`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In [How to read user input in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579266/how-to-read-user-input-in-rust) you can see how to iterate over all lines:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

You can also manually iterate without a for-loop:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut iterator = stdin.lock().lines();
    let line1 = iterator.next().unwrap().unwrap();
    let line2 = iterator.next().unwrap().unwrap();
}
```

You cannot write a one-liner to do what you want. But the following reads a single line (and is exactly the same answer as in [How do I read a single String from standard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528998/how-do-i-read-a-single-string-from-standard-input)):

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let line1 = stdin.lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap();
}
```

---

You can also use the [`text_io`](https://crates.io/crates/text_io) crate for super simple input:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;

fn main() {
    // reads until a \n is encountered
    let line: String = read!("{}\n");
}
```

Comment: What about [Stdin::read_line](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line)?

Comment: @Gerstmann: that function is rather odd to use in my opinion.

Comment: @Gerstmann I just tried it: for some reason it's made to accept a buffer rather than return a string, so you can't compose it with other functions working on strings.

Comment: The separate `let stdin = io::stdin();` line is no longer necessary. You can just do `for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() { ... }`

Answer (score 24):

If you truly want the equivalent to `fgets`, then [@Gerstmann is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186037/read-a-single-line-from-stdin-in-rust#comment48481165_30186553), you should use [`Stdin::read_line`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line). This method accepts a buffer that you have more control of to put the string into:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    stdin.lock().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
    println!("{}", line)
}
```

Unlike C, you can't accidentally overrun the buffer; it will be automatically resized if the input string is too big.

The [answer from @oli_obk - ker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186553/155423) is the idiomatic solution you will see most of the time. In it, the string is managed for you, and the interface is much cleaner.

Answer (score 13):

Read a single line from `stdin`:

```
    let mut line = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)?; // including '\n'
```

You may remove `'\n'` using `line.trim_end()`

Read until EOF:

```
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;
```

---

Using implicit synchronization:

```
use std::io;
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut line = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)?;

    println!("You entered: {}", line);
    Ok(())
}
```

---

Using explicit synchronization:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut handle = stdin.lock();

    let mut line = String::new();
    handle.read_line(&mut line)?;

    println!("You entered: {}", line);
    Ok(())
}
```

---

If you interested in the number of bytes e.g. `n`, use:
`let n = handle.read_line(&mut line)?;`
or
`let n = io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)?;`

Try this:

```
use std::io;
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let n = io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)?;

    println!("{} bytes read", n);
    println!("You entered: {}", line);
    Ok(())
}
```

See [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line)

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Rust 1.62, you can use [`Stdin::lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lines) to get one line (of input) using only one line (of code):

```rust
fn main() {
    let line = std::io::stdin().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap();
}
```

Although `Stdin::lines()` can be used for a single line, it would typically be used for getting multiple.  It simplifies this use case so that it is no longer necessary to worry about lifetimes and locking:

```rust
fn main() {
    for line in std::io::stdin().lines() {
        println!("line: {}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*if you want to leave the* `for`*-loop at some point*

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        match line {
            Err(_) => break,    // with ^Z
            Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        }

    }
    println!("fin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own macro.

```rust
macro_rules! read_line {
  () => {
    {
      let mut str = String::new();
      std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut str).expect("!");
      str
    }
  };
}

fn main () {
  println!("What is your name?");
  let name = read_line!();
  println!("Hello {}.", name.trim());
}
```