# Idiomatic way of mimicking Python's input function in Rust

Tags: rust

I have <s>two</s> three different versions of a function that mimics the `input` function from python.

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader, Write};

// Adapted from https://docs.rs/python-input/0.8.0/src/python_input/lib.rs.html#13-23
fn input_1(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    print!("{}", prompt);
    io::stdout().flush()?;
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    Ok(buffer.trim_end().to_string())
}

// https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6qn3y0/store_user_inputs_in_rust/
fn input_2(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    print!("{}", prompt);
    io::stdout().flush()?;
    BufReader::new(io::stdin())
        .lines()
        .next()
        .ok_or_else(|| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Cannot read stdin"))
        .and_then(|inner| inner)
}

// tranzystorek user on Discord (edited for future reference)
fn input_3(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    print!("{}", prompt);
    std::io::stdout().flush()?;
    BufReader::new(std::io::stdin().lock())
        .lines()
        .take(1)
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let name = input_1("What's your name? ").unwrap();
    println!("Hello, {}!", name);
    let name = input_2("What's your name? ").unwrap();
    println!("Hello, {}!", name);
    let name = input_3("What's your name? ").unwrap();
    println!("Hello, {}!", name);
}
```

But they seem to be very different aproaches and I don't know if there's any advantage using one over the other. From what I've read, having a function like python's `input` is not as simple as it seems which is why there's none in the standard library.

What problems could I face using any of the versions written above? Is there another, more idiomatic, way of writing this `input` function? (2018 edition)

Also, here: [How can I read a single line from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186037) some of the answers use the `lock()` method but I don't get its purpose.

I'm learning Rust coming from python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question of style mostly - both methods are acceptable. Most of the Rustaceans I know would probably favour the second approach, as it's more functional in style but it really doesn't matter in this case.

The key change I'd make is use of the `lock` method in your second example.

To understand the lock method, consider the following scenario: if you application was multithreaded, and two threads attempted to read from `stdin` at the same time, what would happen?

The lock ensures that only one thread can access `stdin` at a time. You always access `stdin` through a lock. In fact, if you look at the implementation of `Stdin::read_line` - the method you call in the first example you'll see it's this very simple one-liner:

```rust
self.lock().read_line(buf)
```

So even when you aren't explicitly calling lock it's still being used behind the scenes.

Secondly `.next()` won't return `None` in this case, as it will block until data has been entered, so you can use `.unwrap()` safely here rather than `.ok_or`/`.and_then`.

Lastly you missed out the `.trim_end()` that you had in `input_1` ;).

```rust
fn input_2(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    print!("{}", prompt);
    io::stdout().flush()?;
    io::stdin()
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .map(|x| x.trim_end().to_owned())
}
```

Comment: The compiler complains that it can't convert the error to `std::io::Error` on `next()?`. Also, is there any advantage of using BufReader?

Comment: A double `unwrap()` solves the problem. Is it safe?

Comment: Apologies my code was completely broken - it was late and I was tired last night - I messed up my result unwraps at the end. I've edited my answer to correct it. Double unwrap is not safe as the result could be in error. Instead you use map to change the "ok" value of the Result.