# Read full lines from stdin including \n until end-of-file

Tags: rust

I want to convert this Python code to Rust:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
   do something to the whole line including \n
```

But I can only find examples that read a single full line (including `\n`) or examples that do not read the `\n`.

It seem this ought to be some of the simplest in the world, but I have been unable to find it.

Comment: To clarify: You want to read _all_ available lines from stdin until no more is available, right?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186553/1639625) answer your question? (Question actually asks for reading a single line, but top answer shown reading all lines.)

Comment: *"I can only find examples that read a single full line (including \n)"* - isn't this as simple as putting it in a loop then?

Comment: @tobias_k The top answer uses `lines()`, which [**doesn't** include](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) the terminating `\n`.

Comment: @tobias_k Correct. The answer you link to eats the \n. I do not want it to eat the \n. Apart from that, the answer is fine (it is BTW one of the answers I found).

Comment: @kmdreko The example that reads a single line does not show how to figure out when eof() is set. Also I would assume there is a simpler way (like Perl's `while(<>)` or Python's `for i in sys.stdin`).

Answer (score 8):

Both [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) and [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) offer convenience API for iterating over the lines in a file, they just chose different tradeoffs of convenience vs completeness. Rust has chosen extra convenience and strips the newlines at the expense of being able to distinguish whether the final line ends with a terminator. Python has chosen the opposite, at the expense of all line parsers having to take the final `\n` into account, and also take into account that it's *optional*.

But `BufRead::lines()` is just a convenience method; if it doesn't meet your needs, you can always use [`read_line()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) directly:

```
let mut line = String::new();
while input.read_line(&mut line)? != 0 {
    let line = std::mem::take(&mut line);
    // ...
}
```

If you use this kind of code in multiple places, or just want the convenience of a `for` loop, you can abstract it into a utility function that returns an iterator, such as:

```
fn full_lines(mut input: impl BufRead) -> impl Iterator<Item = io::Result<String>> {
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        let mut vec = String::new();
        match input.read_line(&mut vec) {
            Ok(0) => None,
            Ok(_) => Some(Ok(vec)),
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        }
    })
}
```

Then you can use a `for` loop similar to the one in Python:

```
for line in full_lines(io::stdin().lock()) {
    let line = line?;
    // ...
}
```

With additional effort it is even possible to make `full_lines` a method on anything that implements `BufRead`:

```
trait FullLines: BufRead + Sized {
    fn full_lines<'a>(self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = io::Result<String>> + 'a>
    where
        Self: 'a,
    {
        Box::new(full_lines(self))
    }
}

// Provide a blanket implementation of FullLines for any T
// that implements BufRead
impl<T: BufRead> FullLines for T {}

// Usage:

use FullLines;

for line in io::stdin().lock().full_lines() {
    let line = line?;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. One thing I don't understand though: why do you use `"".to_string()` to create your buffer,  instead of just `String::new()` ?

Comment: Since `read_line` returns the number of bytes read, you can also replace the `while` condition with just `input.read_line(&mut line)? > 0`. Smart use of `take`, though, I never thought of using it like that.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks, I've now simplified it as suggested. The more complex formulation remained from my original experiments with making the `while` condition also provide return the new line immediately, so the user doesn't have to remember to reset it at the end of each loop iteration, [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef3acdf942a8d7eb4e9f9c61acb39cd7). The version with `mem::take()` is much simpler, but the unnecessary test remained from a version in which I'd drop the `read_line` return value.